# MySQL Order by Amount of same Category not working when Amount the same

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, sql-order-by

I having a mySQL query with which I order a list by the amount of the same column "category"

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.category 
FROM table mt 
JOIN ( SELECT category, 
COUNT(*) AS ct FROM table GROUP by category ) sq 
ON mt.category = sq.category 
ORDER by sq.ct DESC, id ASC
```

so I can order this list:

```
id| category
1 | Apple
2 | Apple
3 | Cherry
4 | Banana
5 | Banana
6 | Apple
```

to this:

```
1 | Apple
2 | Apple
6 | Apple
4 | Banana
5 | Banana
3 | Cherry
```

Everythnig is working as expected but when we have the same amount of objects with the same category like this :

```
1 | Apple
2 | Apple
3 | Cherry
4 | Banana
5 | Banana
6 | Apple
7 | Banana
```

the query mix them up and don't seperate them properly and the result looks like this:

```
1 | Apple
2 | Apple
4 | Banana
5 | Banana
6 | Apple
7 | Banana
3 | Cherry
```

Does someone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, window functions are the best way to write this.  I want to point out that in earlier versions, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.category 
FROM table mt 
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table mt2 WHERE mt2.category = mt.category),
         mt2.catgory, id;
```

With an index on `mt(category)` this might even be more efficient than the aggregation method.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the `category` to the `order by` clause:

```
ORDER by sq.ct DESC, mt.category, mt.id ASC
```

Note that, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can simplify the query by using window functions rather than joining with an aggregate query:

```
SELECT id, category
FROM mytable mt
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY category) DESC,
    category,
    id
```